# Using variables within a variable function

Tags: jquery, variables

I am trying to run a variable function then use stated variables within it. Code below

```js
var load_map = (function(){
$('.map-container').html("<div class='loader'><div class='window'></div></div>");
    $('.map-container').load( station);
    history.pushState(null, null, stationUrl);
});
```

So once I have this I then run it within an if statement with the stated variables before it but for some reason I can't get them to insert.

```js
if ( values[handle] === '1' ) {
var station = 'lawrence-hill';
var stationUrl = '#lawrence-hill';
load_map();
```

}

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). (You're already using Stack Snippets, but incorrectly; there's nothing **runnable** there.) Provided the code in the first code block above *closes over* the variables in the second code block, that should work. It's not the right way to do it (pass them in as arguments), but it should work.

Comment: As T.J.Crowder said it should work and in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thu0rp3e/) you can see that it tries to load `lawrence-hill`.

Comment: Ok sorry I ve edited my question. The function and variables are being called within an if statement.

Comment: Where is `values[handle]` declared?

Comment: The if statement is from a noUiSlider. It basically states that when the slider has a value then this function should happen.  Sorry I'm maybe not being very clear.